# solving problems in session?

Tags: php, session

I have created two pages , one is index.php and admin.php . In the first page or index.php , i have created a loggin form so that i can access the admin.php page trough the loggin or like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peSSb.jpg)

Now by logging in i go to admin.php page. Here is the question what i want to ask about that now when ever i click the back button or next button in the chrome. I am returning to the admin.php page . I have tryed the session_start() and the if(!isset($password) || !isset($user)){}. But this code for obvious reasons doesnt work . So can someone help me out with this ?

The code for the example is here index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <title>Admin</title>
    </head>
<body>
    





<a href="reset.php">Reset</a>

    
    
    


    <div class="image">

        <img src="img/adi.png" alt="image">                                         <!-- image -->

    </div>



    
    
    
    
    
    
    <form action="inc/login.php" method="POST"><br>
        
        <p class="title">Log In</p>
    
        <label for="Username">User :</label>
            <input type="text" name="username"             id="user"> <br>            <!--username  -->
        
            
        <label for="Password">Password :</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"         id="password"    ><br><br>        <!-- password  --> 


        <label for="showpassword" class="showpassword">Show Password</label>   
            
            
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"   id="chk" ><br><br>               <!-- checkbox -->
        
        
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" >                       <!--  enter -->

        
       
    
    </form>
    
    <?php
    
    if(!isset($_GET['Login'])){
            exit();
        }else{

            $check=$_GET['Login'];
        
        
            if($check=="userEmpty"){
                
                echo "<p class='class_login'>user is empty</p> ";
            
            }elseif($check=="passwordEmpty"){
                
                echo "<p class='class_login'>password is empty</p> ";
            
            }elseif($check=="wrongUser"){
                
                echo "<p class='class_login'>user is wrong</p> ";
            
            }elseif($check=="Password"){
                
                echo "<p class='class_login'>password is wrong</p> ";
            
            };
    
    
        } ;
    ?>

 <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the code for the admin.php is this one :

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($username) || !isset($password)){

    header("location:index.php?data=closed");
    exit();
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <script>
        window.history.forward();
    </script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="top">
        <a href="inc/logout.php">Log Out</a>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: It's quite unclear what's happening here. Can you please add the relevant code and describe what you want the code to be doing?

Comment: Okey i will post the code here  and you can tell me what is happening :

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the issue is.

Comment: You've added the code but you still haven't described what it does different from what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using of `session_start` you need to store something in the session, using something like this:

```php
$_SESSION['userId'] = <value>;
```

which must be set in your `login.php` and checked by your `admin.php` if user has access rigths to visit secured page. I.e. you need to check:

```php
if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && $_SESSION['userId'] == <value>) {
  // access granted
}
```